# Alexa Custom Skill Development HTTP Error 405 in Response

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am developing a custom skill in Alexa, and just trying to return a hard coded response on a https service endpoint on port 8443 based on my sample utterances and intent schema defined on Amazon Alexa Console.

While testing from Alexa Service Emulator i am getting error **There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP 405 : Method Not Allowed**

While accessing the endpoint URL from POSTMEN i do get below mentioned response

```
{"response":{"shouldEndSession":true,"outputSpeech":{"text":"All appliance are working as expected","type":"PlainText"}},"sessionAttributes":{},"version":"1.0"}
```

I am finding it hard to understand where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa is pretty picky when it comes to hosting skills externally. It sounds like this could be the issue. It can be done, you just have the follow the rules Alexa defines.

[From the docs](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service#requirements-for-your-web-service)

The service must support HTTP over SSL/TLS, leveraging an Amazon-trusted certificate.

The service must accept requests on port 443

For testing, Amazon accepts different methods for providing a certificate.
[For details, see the “About the SSL Options” section of Registering and Managing Custom Skills in the Developer Portal](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/registering-and-managing-alexa-skills-in-the-developer-portal#h2_ssl).